# How to redirect url to another site in httpd.conf with the real name

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

My config is easy : 2 Apache Servers

- Server 1 : 'IP1' with domain (test.com)
- Server 2 : 'IP2' without domain

In the file httpd.conf of my server 1, i would like to access :

- to the tomcat installed on server 1 with the url : test.com
- to the apache of server 2, which has virtualhost, with the url : test.com/server2

*Httpd.conf / Server 1*

```
RewriteRule ^/server2$ http://'IP2'/web/test.php/  [L]
ProxyPass / ajp://'IP1':PORT/ retry=5
```

It works, but the second URL doesn't display **test.com/server2** but **http://'IP2'/web/test.php/**.
How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Having `http://'IP2'` as part of the rewrite rule's target automatically 302 redirects the browser. But since it's on a different machine and you don't want the URL address bar in the browser to change, you need to use mod_proxy instead of mod_rewrite.

Change the `RewriteRule` line to `ProxyPass` instead so that it reverse proxies the request instead of redirecting:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/server2$ http://'IP2'/web/test.php/
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively, you could also add the `P` flag to your `RewriteRule` to make it proxy the request.  However, [the mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) says that's inefficient, and recommends using `ProxyPassMatch` as suggested in the answer above.

Comment: It doesn't work with this syntax :

ProxyPassMatch ^/server2$ http://'IP2'/web/test.php/

I have 503 error ...

In the file '/var/log/httpd/error.log' (server1), i have this log : 

[error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to  (IP2:80) failed

Comment: yes it works with the url http://'IP2'/web/test.php and it works too with the rewrite rule syntax, except of i want the url displayed is test.com/server2 and not http://'IP2'/web/test.php

Comment: @user1761263 so you don't need that trailing slash after `test.php` (that you had in your example)?

Comment: OK it works; it was my 'IP2' who was wrong; i replaced by the internal ip (private ip) and it works. Thanks